# It is not working when I pass the value from a variable to the JSON code but if I hardcode the value it works in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, api

It is not working when I pass the value from a variable to the JSON code but if I hardcode the value it works.

Code I tried:

```
$countries = 'LK,AU,US';
$allowedCountries = str_getcsv($countries, ",");
$allowedCountries = ('","' . implode('","', $allowedCountries) . '');
var_dump ($allowedCountries);
```

Output:
"","LK","AU","US"

The issue is when I pass the output from the variable to the below API code it doesn't work. but if I hardcode the same output like this *'countrySet' => ["","LK","AU","US"]* in the below API code it works.

API  Code:

```
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
            "ttl" => 300,
            'ipGeoRules' => json_encode([
                [
                    'action' => 'true',
                    'ipSet' => [],
                    'countrySet' => [$allowedCountries]
                ]
            ]),
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be a bit confused with the types here, strings versus arrays. By the looks of it, you can probably just use `explode()` on `$countries` and pass that result to your `countrySet` parameter.

```
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
        "ttl" => 300,
        'ipGeoRules' => json_encode([
            [
                'action' => 'true',
                'ipSet' => [],
                'countrySet' => explode(",", $countries)
            ]
        ])
```

The value is an array, but since you use `json_encode()`, it will become encoded to a string.

As a footnote, do you really need to use `json_encode()` twice? Should it not just be needed on the full array (and not on the outer array, and on the `ipGeoRules` parameter)?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have been trying to pass the value inside the square brackets like this 'countrySet' => [$allowedCountries]. When I removed them and pass the values as you have done, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you will need to convert string to an array.

Try echo gettype($allowedCountries)  to see if it is a string or an array.

Convert the countries to array .

Answer (score 1):

The hard coded value:

```
'countrySet' => ["","LK","AU","US"]
```

is different than

```
'countrySet' => [$allowedCountries]
```

Because `$allowedCountries` is already an array of values, it will result in a nested array:

```
'countrySet' => [
   [
     "LK",
     "AU",
     "US",
   ]
],
```

Comment: It's not an array though. It's a string, since they did `$allowedCountries = ('","' . implode('","', $allowedCountries) . '');`